# Dual Boot ( Windows 7 32bit and Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit )

Tags: dual-boot

I am using (windows 7 - 32bit) Please advise can I install ( Ubuntu 14.04 LTS -  64bit ) as dual boot? Or should I install Ubuntu 32bit alongside.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your processor?

Comment: System Model: OptiPlex 745
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6300 @ 1.86Ghz (2CPUs)
Memory: 4GB

Comment: [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E6300 (2M Cache, 1.86 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)](http://ark.intel.com/products/27248/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6300-2M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) specifications -> Instruction Set = 64-bit. 64-bit operating system is compatible with your hardware and recommended for  your hardware. The CPU is a bit slow, so its a toss-up between either Ubuntu or Xubuntu, and I would choose Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no cross-effect with dual-boot, where the *other* OS is 32-bit.**

---

Generally you should use 64-bit if you have at least 2GB RAM, and your PC/laptop is reasonably modern. **Ubuntu** 64-bit includes full 32-bit support.

*Possible exceptions would be: need to support UEFI (avoid 32-bit), or (laptop with) Intel Atom graphics (needs 32-bit driver).*

Answer (score 1):

First check your CPU instructions.If it has 64 bit instructions, then you can run any 32 or 64-bit systems as far as I know.

Comment: System Model: OptiPlex 745,
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6300 @ 1.86Ghz (2CPUs),
Memory: 4GB

Comment: Can u please go through your Computer's properties and tell me the system type of your computer?

Comment: Well I have gone through web and found that your's having a 64-bit architecture.So you can install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.It won't give you any problem..

Answer (score 0):

Dell Optiplex 745 will probably run 64-bit Ubuntu just fine.

1. It uses a [64-bit capable processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/27248/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6300-2M-Cache-1_86-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) .
2. There are examples on web where people [have installed and run 64-bit OS on the system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOEVgTri7Jw) successfully .